# Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, mysqli

I have a problem with Json pars, I have seen tons of users had this problem I saw them all but I couldn't understand where my error is in my code! Sorry if this is duplicate!

First file index.html:

This is in the head section of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_json_data(){
    var databox = document.getElementById("databox");
    var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( "POST", "test.php", true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
            databox.innerHTML = "";
            var d = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
            for(var o in d){
                if(d[o].title){
                    results.innerHTML = "";
                    databox.innerHTML += '<p><a href="page.php?id="'+d[o].id+'">'+d[o].title+'</a><br />';
                    databox.innerHTML += ''+d[o].cd+'</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    x.send("limit=4&field1="+field1);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
```

This is in the body section of the file:

```
<form id="form" method="post" onSubmit="return false;">
<textarea id="field1" name="field1" placeholder="Input some text here..."></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="ajax_json_data();">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="databox"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_data();</script>
```

The second file test.php:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/json");
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && $_POST['field1'] != "") {
    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    require_once("db_conx.php");
    $sqlString = "INSERT INTO test_ajax (title) VALUES ('$field1')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlString) or die (mysqli_error()); 
}
if(isset($_POST['limit'])){
    $limit = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['limit']);
    require_once("db_conx.php");
    $i = 0;
    $jsonData = '{';
    $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM test_ajax ORDER BY creationdate DESC LIMIT $limit";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlString);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $i++;
        $id = $row["id"]; 
        $title = $row["title"];
        $cd = $row["creationdate"];
        $cd = strftime("%B %d, %Y", strtotime($cd));
        $jsonData .= '"article'.$i.'":{"id":"'.$id.'","title":"'.$title.'","cd":"'.$cd.'"},';
    }
    $jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
    $jsonData .= '}';
    echo $jsonData;
}
?>
```

And mysqli table has an id, a title and a timestamp, I have tested the data in JSONLint and it's completely valid...Maybe some details that I give it's not necessary but nevermind... **So it returns this error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data ... var d = JSON.parse(x.responseText);** Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `json_encode`? You're basically building you're own buggy JSON when you can simply use the built-in function.

Comment: Thought json_encode was only for arrays..How can I implement it in this.. sorry I am new to javascript and I try to understand some things..! thanks for your response!

Comment: Manual says -- "The value being encoded can be any type except a resource." -- http://us1.php.net/json_encode. Work with your `$row`  to build your own data structure, then serialize that.

Comment: I did that ..but again it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem..the problem was that my host provider send me some code together with my json response so the response from json was invalid..! Thank you for your feedback!